# differential of a function $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I struggling in finding the linear application ( the differential ) of the function above
$$
f\left(x,y\right)=\left(xe^{y},ye^{x}\right)
$$

When i write $f\left(a+h\right)$ with $a=\left(x,y\right)$ and $h=\left(h_1,h_2\right)$ i have
\begin{align*}\displaystyle f\left(a+h\right)=f\left(x+h_1,y+h_2\right)&=\left(\left(x+h_1\right)e^{y+h_2},\left(y+h_2\right)e^{x+h_1}\right)\\
&=\left(xe^{y},ye^{x}\right)+\left(xe^{y}\left(e^{h_2}-1\right)+h_1e^{y+h_2},ye^{x}\left(e^{h_1}-1\right)+h_2e^{x+h_1}\right)\end{align*}

Which doesnt make an obvious linear application appears...
 Any help please ?
I'm quite rusty on this subject...

Comment: You could expand the exponentials in $h_i$ to get the linear part.

Comment: Why would you expect the differential to be linear? Show me with $f(x) =x^3$ please.

Comment: The definition of a differential $df_{a}$ is to be a linear application so that $f\left(a+h\right)=f\left(a\right)+\text{d}f_{a}+o\left(\left\|h\right\|\right)$ isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x,y)=(f^1(x,y),f^2(x,y))$ the derivative is given by
$$
Df(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}f^1_x&f^1_y\\
f^2_x&f^2_y \end{bmatrix}
$$
So yours is 
$$
Df(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}e^y&xe^y\\
ye^x&e^x \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then 
$$
f(x+h_1,y+h_2)\approx f(x,y)+Df(x,y)(h_1,h_2)\\
=(xe^y,ye^x)+(e^yh_1+xe^yh_2,ye^xh_1+e^xh_2)
$$

Comment: Just a remark, i think it should be $xe^{y}$ in the upper right corner of the matrix.

Comment: @Atmos you are very right, I am editing